# merging columns when column name is an integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my dataframe:

```
A   B     1    2    5

1   1     26    5   5     
2   6     4     2   2    
2   3     8     7   7     
2   4     3    10   19
```

So here you can see that columns are 'A' 'B' '1' '2' '5'
I want to create a function that accepts one argument as int and then creates a new dataframe that has 'A' 'B' columns and column which was passed as arugment.
so it would go like this, however im not sure how to get the column when its name is an int any ideas ? Thanks!:

```
def merge(arg):
    new_df=pd.concat([df.A, df.B, df.arg], axis=1 )
merge(5)

A   B     5

1   1     5   
2   6     2  
2   3     7   
2   4     19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest solution is selecting by subset with [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
def merge(arg):
     return df[['A', 'B', str(arg)]].copy()

print (merge(5))
   A  B   5
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  19
```

---

Solutions with `concat` if column is `str` only convert to `str` - works nice, but slowier:

```
def merge(arg):
     return pd.concat([df.A, df.B, df[str(arg)]], axis=1 )

print (merge(5))
   A  B   5
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  19
```

If `int`:

```
def merge(arg):
     return pd.concat([df.A, df.B, df[arg]], axis=1 )

print (merge(5))
   A  B   5
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  19
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge(arg):
    return df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', str(arg)]]

merge(2)

   A  B   2
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  10
```

You could also imbed `if/else` logic to make it more robust

```
def merge(arg):
    arg = arg if arg in df.columns else str(arg)
    return df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', arg]]

print(merge(2))

   A  B   2
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  10
```

Or with a bit of clever intersection

```
def merge(arg):
    cols = df.columns.intersection(['A', 'B', arg, str(arg)])
    return df.loc[:, cols]

print(merge(2))

   A  B   2
0  1  1   5
1  2  6   2
2  2  3   7
3  2  4  10
```